# Youtube API Statuscode 403 "The caller does not have the permission" even tho I have the permission

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use the YouTube API to set a video thumbnail on an hourly bases with a cronjob. Most of the time it is working flawlessly - the thumbnail is set properly. But there are some hours of the day where i get this response:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The code im using to is the PHP sample from YouTube - OAuth:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set?hl=en

It's super strange because it's pretty much 7 hours each day where it's not working.
The usage is below the API threshold as you can see here: (the red line are the maximum allowed queries per day)
[image]

But the weirdest part is - if i check the usage of the API through YT Console i can clearly see that something is not working. See the spickes in the chart below. Each spike has nearly the exact same duration. It's exactly the timeframe when i get the error response above.
[image]

I should also point out that I use this on a YT Brand account. I tried to set this up on a new VM with new Domain, new auth token - nothing works. What drives me crazy is the fact that the script runs for about 17 hours a day, but then suddenly the error message comes. So it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'd recommend to address this issue directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/). They have all the info for to know what's actually happening.

Comment: Hey thanks gonna do that as well  I just found this site which was stating i should raise a stackoverflow question.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: Sorry, @Christian Meyer, they don't here on SO (not in my experience). That's why I recommended to go there.

Comment: See a bit down, @Christian Meyer,  on [that page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) you quoted: ***[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) Something wrong? Send us a bug report!*** and ***Issue Tracker: [File a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) / [Request a feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) / [See open issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600)***.

Answer (score -1):

So after days of struggle I figured out with help of the Google team that I hit a quota that is not tracked from the API team. Apparently it's a quota by YouTube in general.

My tip is - just try to upload the thumbnail manually through YouTube.com video manager. I got the correct response that I actually did hit a YT quota for the account.

In my humble opinion the error message of the YT API with the "permission" is just wrong and misleading. And second I think YT API shouldn't rely on the YT upload thumbnail interface quota. Or at least should show the quota of a given account that you try to set the thumbnail.

I have yet no solution to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue but I have millions of quota left... Did they mention it could be anything else?

Comment: @NullReference I have the same problem (not hitting the quota) but can't change the Thumbnail.
I opened a bug issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201895457?pli=1
They marked it as "intended behaviour" and referred to a page. But in my opinion this is wrong for many reason. First the error message is completely missleading and second in my opinion the UI Thumbnail change has to be independend from the API thumbnail change. I understand the security measurement UI vise but not in the API.

Please open an issue there and refer to mine and upvote. Let's make this issue visible.

Comment: I'm going to test that the limited on # of thumbnails uploaded is the source of the problem and report back

Comment: Were you able to test it? You couldn't upload thumbnails via the youtube UI when you receive the error right?

Comment: We test via the API and on the 100th thumbnail upload, we got the error.  We're testing today if it resets daily.

Comment: Yeah that also matches my observation and after that you can not change a thumbnail via the UI or the API.